# Rearrange LIST (Ascending Order)

Tags: prolog

Assume that I have a list which is incorrect sequence.

How can I re-arrange the list in ascending order?

E.g:

```
dog(bull,chiwawa,lucky).
```

And I inputted like `dog(chiwawa,lucky,bull)`.

How can I rearrange them to become `dog(bull,chiwawa,lucky)`?

Just made it to easier to compare.

Comment: Are those variables or one-letter atoms? If they are atoms, can't you just sort them? If they are variables, how is their order defined?

Comment: i had modify the example to you.
assume i already define a predicate which contain a lot of atoms.

Answer (score 0):

sorting structure arguments it's a bit out of Prolog 'mainstream' coding. That's because arguments are really placeholders (exactly like *columns* in a RDB).

You can do by means of univ ([=..](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=%28=..%29/2))/2 and [msort](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=msort/2)/2

```
?- Unsorted = dog(chiwawa,lucky,bull), Unsorted =.. [Functor|UnsortedArgs], msort(UnsortedArgs, Args), Sorted =.. [Functor|Args].
```

yields

```
Unsorted = dog(chiwawa, lucky, bull),
Functor = dog,
UnsortedArgs = [chiwawa, lucky, bull],
Args = [bull, chiwawa, lucky],
Sorted = dog(bull, chiwawa, lucky).
```

Of course, you probably should switch representation to lists, or will have an hard time with the remaining of your program. If you are trying to represent some kind of elementary classification, you could use library([pairs](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?section=pairs)), and go with a list of `Key-Elements`. Something like dog-[bull, chiwawa, lucky].

Keeping Elements sorted, you can use library([ordsets](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc/swi/library/ordsets.pl)), with many powerful operations implemented efficiently. Much easier, really...